# Spring Security Restful Application with Custom User Authentication

Tags: java, spring, jakarta-ee, spring-security, spring-security-rest

I am trying to accomplish Spring security token mechanism with custom user authentication, but I can't configure Spring because of restful application doesn't have form login page. When a user post a request to /authenticate page with username and password, the service will check this user in mysql database.  After then, the service will automatically create a token then send to the user. User will access any method in the service by using this token.

Comment: What's your question exactly ?

Comment: How can I accomplish this configuration in Spring security